# Rails + Cocoon: update nested resource instead of destroy it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy, cocoon-gem

My current Cocoon / nested form works very well.
However I would like to change this behavior:

**Main model**:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :varietals, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:grape_id].blank? && a[:id].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
```

Instead of deleting the varietal object with allow_destroy, I want to update its status field to 0 when it is destroyed.

It is possible to call a function in this line to do that ? Should I update the varietal model instead ?

Something like:

```
varietal.update_attributes(:status => 0)
```

when one nested resource is deleted by the user.

Thanks.

EDIT: data post after an edit of the main form and the removing of a nested varietal to help:

```
"varietals_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"grape_attributes"=>{"id"=>"168"}, "grape_id"=>"168", "percent"=>"20", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"32709368-3496-47EA-A386-B1CCECA0BAEF"}},
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember about coocoon, it just adds an attribute `_destroy` to the object hash, so I think you can just handle it in a callback on your `varietal` model and remove `allow_destroy: true`.

Comment: If I add a callback such before_destroy in the varietal model, I can maybe change the status field, but it will destroy the object just after, isn't it ? I edited my message to post the data updated after a destroy.

Comment: If you remove `allow_destroy`, it won't mark the object for destruction.

Comment: I did it, but my callback is not called in varietals model (and seems logical).

Comment: OK, I overwrite the destroy method in the varietals model and it works. I keep `allow_destroy => true` for this to work.

Comment: Did you use a `before_save` or `before_destroy` callback? Destroy won't work without `allow_destroy`.

Comment: I override `destroy` and use `allow_destroy` set to true.